# $http PATCH method not sending data server side

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, laravel, patch

I am new in angularjs making a crud using `Laravel` and `angularjs` i am using a function that will be use for both update and save my function code is

```
 $scope.save = function (modalstate, id) {
        var url = $scope.url;
        var method = "POST";
        console.log(modalstate);
        //append id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
        if (modalstate === 'edit') {
            url += "/" + id;
            method = 'PATCH';
        }
        var data = {};
        data = $scope.formdata;

        if (!$("#myform").isValid()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('request');
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                data: data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    console.log(angular.toJson(data));
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("data", [angular.toJson(data)]);

                    if (typeof (data.logo) != "undefined")
                    {
                        formData.append("file", data.logo);
                    }
                    console.log(formData);
                    return formData;
                },
            }).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //  location.reload();
            }).error(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
            });
        }
```

Above function is working perfectly when i store the record. But on edit the record for update i am using `PATCH` request but now there is problem by using `PATCH` request i am receiving empty array on server side. kindly please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you show us your `controller\action` and provide the code of route registering

Comment: i am just using route with resource `Route::resource('people','PeopleController');`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel makes use of [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing) in order to provide better support for RESTful interfaces like the one you are trying to build using `Route::resource`. Which means that instead of using method `PATCH`, you use the `POST` method and pass a `_method` key with value `PATCH` along with your request data.

So your code might look like this:

```
 $scope.save = function (modalstate, id) {
        var url = $scope.url,
            data = $scope.formdata;

        //append id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
        if (modalstate === 'edit') {
            url += "/" + id;
            data = angular.merge(data, {_method: 'PATCH'});
        }

        if (!$("#myform").isValid()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('request');
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    console.log(angular.toJson(data));
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("data", [angular.toJson(data)]);

                    if (typeof (data.logo) != "undefined")
                    {
                        formData.append("file", data.logo);
                    }
                    console.log(formData);
                    return formData;
                },
            }).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //  location.reload();
            }).error(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
            });
        }
```